# Summing up the amount of time spent on a given event title on Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I use Google Calendar to track my time throughout the day.

Is there any convenient way to summarize how much time I have spent in a given activity in a given period of time? (E.g. how time I spent on research over the last 10 days).

[image]

Comment: @pnuts Thanks, I'll give a shot with a test account sometime!

Comment: @pnuts The remainder of the answer was "This should help you in getting that!", so it wasn't very helpful.